# Append more than one field in v-text in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vuejs. How do we append more than one fields in v-text.

I wanted to displat result.stu_fname with result.stu_lname

tried with  v-text="result.stu_lname"."". v-text="result.stu_fname" didn't work

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model ="search_uin" placeholder="Type and wait!">
    <ul v-if="results.length > 0">
        <li v-for="result in results"  v-text="result.stu_lname"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There several ways to do it.

1. Use simple string concatenation inside v-text

   ```
    <li v-for="result in results"  v-text="result.stu_lname+' ' + result.stu_fname"></li>
   ```
2. Without v-text

   {{result.stu_lname}} {{result.stu_fname}}

You can also created a method where u will pass result and return what u want.
Also dont forget to add [key for v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).